# React Send API call on Link hover to preload data

Tags: reactjs, preloader, preloading, react-lazy-load

I'm trying to improve the UI of my React app, and one thing I want to try and work out is how to pre fire an API call when a user hovers over a link, so by the time they're clicked through, the data has already been loaded and `FakeAPI.jsx` has already populated the state with the data from the API call

Currently I've got the below:

```
//Home.jsx

import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';

const Home = () => {
    return (
        <div className="links">
            //I would want to load the API call when a user hovers on the below link
            <Link to="/fakeApi">Fake Api</Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

And then the API call

```
//FakeApi.jsx
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const FakeApi = () => {

const [data, setData] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
    setTimeout(() => {
        //simulates an api call to the backend
        setData(['1','2','3'])
    }, 250);
}, [])



    return (
        <div>
            Fake Api call
            {data.map(entry=>(
                <div key={entry}>number is {entry}</div>
            ))}
        </div>
    );
};

export default FakeApi;
```

The only solution i've come up with so far is to put the api call in `home.jsx`, and then call it on hover and pass the data through as props,

as per below:

```
//Home.jsx
import React from 'react';
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom';
import LinkWithPreload from '../shared/LinkWithPreload';

const Home = () => {

    const [data, setData] = useState([])

    useEffect(()=>{
        setTimeout(() => {
            //simulates an api call to the backend
            setData(['1','2','3'])
        }, 1000);
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className="links">
            <Link to="/fakeApi" props={data}>Fake Api</Link>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

however in reality `home.jsx` is a very big file with several other functions and API calls, and I'm trying to keep it tidy so I'm looking for another solution - to keep each call to a route,

Thanks for your help!